# Net core 3.1 SAML2 Web-sso, need help / working sample code

Tags: .net-core, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I need to get a Web SSO SAML2 integration to work. The end goal is to use MS-ADFS as idP - for testing purposes I have made an Okta account and registered a Web-app there.

I'm using this simple SAML2 nuget package, https://github.com/jitbit/AspNetSaml

I have a simple Net core 3.1 webapp as template.

As far as I can tell, the auth-request goes well - I can see in the logs at Okta that I'm signed in and all is well.

But the next step, SAML Assertion, I get a HTTP Error 400 before my code is run at all, feels like the webserver says "No thanks". I've tried hosting in Visual Studio and in IIS. I use a self-signed SSL certificate.

X.509 certificate is provided by Okta - but I don't think it is used, since the 400 error occurs before my assertion code is run.

I have installed a SAML-spy in the browser and I can see that okta posts a SAML-Assertion-Header back:

```
{
        "timestamp": "2021-09-17T18:05:50.058Z",
        "url": "https://localhost:44376/Identity/Account/saml",
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "protocol": "SAML",
        "messageType": "Response",
        "message": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><saml2p:Response Destination=\"https://localhost:44376/Identity/Account/saml\" ID=\"id2486584958412951260643647\" InResponseTo=\"_d0af4658-74d6-4c6a-a358-01048f61e3f3\" IssueInstant=\"2021-09-17T18:05:49.759Z\" Version=\"2.0\" xmlns:saml2p=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol\"><saml2:Issuer Format=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity\" xmlns:saml2=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion\">http://www.okta.com/exk1up01urIhOtZ9C5d7</saml2:Issuer><saml2p:Status><saml2p:StatusCode Value=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success\"/></saml2p:Status><saml2:Assertion ID=\"id2486584958482922407856721\" IssueInstant=\"2021-09-17T18:05:49.759Z\" Version=\"2.0\" xmlns:saml2=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion\"><saml2:Issuer Format=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity\">http://www.okta.com/exk1up01urIhOtZ9C5d7</saml2:Issuer><saml2:Subject><saml2:NameID Format=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress\">lars.siden@softronic.se</saml2:NameID><saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method=\"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer\"><saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo=\"_d0af4658-74d6-4c6a-a358-01048f61e3f3\" NotOnOrAfter=\"2021-09-17T18:10:49.759Z\" Recipient=\"https://localhost:44376/Identity/Account/saml\"/></saml2:SubjectConfirmation></saml2:Subject><saml2:Conditions NotBefore=\"2021-09-17T18:00:49.759Z\" NotOnOrAfter=\"2021-09-17T18:10:49.759Z\"><saml2:AudienceRestriction><saml2:Audience>LZSAML</saml2:Audience></saml2:AudienceRestriction></saml2:Conditions><saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant=\"2021-09-17T18:05:49.759Z\" SessionIndex=\"_d0af4658-74d6-4c6a-a358-01048f61e3f3\"><saml2:AuthnContext><saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:X509</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef></saml2:AuthnContext></saml2:AuthnStatement></saml2:Assertion></saml2p:Response>"
    },
```

Comment: think I solved it - atleast  I get into the code now :-) I added this 

[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]

To the SAML.-assertion page (on the PageModel class)

So now I get into the code - next problem, Assertion is invalid he says...

// Lars

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you need the attribute:

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
```

On the PageModel class for the page that does the SAML Assertion